# Kentico smart search default option

Tags: kentico

I have a smart search filter that is filtering news items by tags which all works fine.

The query for the filter dropdown is as follows:

SELECT 'DocumentTags', TagName, TagName FROM CMS_Tag WHERE ##WHERE## ORDER BY ##ORDERBY##

I need to know how to add a default of "All" (essesntially no filter) to this list, but cannot work out how to do it.

The only option I have currently is to tag all documents with "All" tag then this would show up, but hopefully there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically query a default of of *empty string*, *empty string*, *display text* and use a UNION to bind it with the set of results to actually filter by:

```
SELECT '','','-- Select a Value --'

UNION

SELECT 'DocumentTags', TagName, TagName
FROM CMS_Tag 
WHERE ##WHERE## 
ORDER BY ##ORDERBY##
```